# Why is Intellisense not working in MVC View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

no yellow lines color in <%= %> tags although @ shows in yellow on view
`<div>
       the  customer id = <%= Model.id %><br />
       the customer code is = <%= Model.customercode % ><br/>
       the customer amount is= <%= Model.amount % >
    </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `@` shows as a server tag and not `<% %>`, then you most likely are using Razor as view engine instead of the classic ASPX style view engine.